# How to I write a repository with effective Dispose() in EF 3.5 -4.0?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, dispose

i try to write a kind of repository for effective Add,Update, Delete etc. But i am so confused how can i dispose my 2 class ( ErpEntities and DataRepository) there are more advise but also more conflicts on google. i want to make disposing after return value. Shorthly and effectivelly :(

Best regards...

```
namespace WinApp.EF
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (ErpEntities erp = new ErpEntities())
            {
                erp.SaveCustomer(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ErpEntities : IDisposable
    {

        public int SaveCustomer(string Name, string SurName)
        {
            using (DataRepository<Customer> repository = new DataRepository<Customer>(new TestErpEntities()))
            {
                return repository.Add(new Customer() { Name = Name, SurName = SurName });
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

    }


    public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class
    {
         int Add(T entity);
    }

    public class DataRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {

        private TestErpEntities _context;

        public DataRepository()
        {
        }   

       public DataRepository(TestErpEntities context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public int Add(T entity)
        {
            _context.AddObject(typeof(T).Name, entity);
            int saveValue = _context.SaveChanges();
            return saveValue;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_context != null)
                _context.Dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look this article. It might help: http://bit.ly/bF7jL3.

Comment: why make life difficult? use a DI container and let it dispose of the context for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
public class ErpEntities : IDisposable 
{ 

    public int SaveCustomer(string Name, string SurName) 
    {
        using(DataRepository repository = new DataRepository<Customer>(new TestErpEntities()))
        { 
           return repository.Add(new Customer() { Name = Name, SurName = SurName });  
        } // This using statment ensures that the DataRepository is Dispose()'d when the method exits
    } 


    #region IDisposable Members 

    public void Dispose() 
    { 
       // You could eliminate this as there's nothing in your 
       // ErpEntities class that needs disposing
    } 

    #endregion 
} 

public class DataRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class     
{     

    private TestErpEntities _context;     

    public DataRepository()     
    {     
    }     

    public DataRepository(TestErpEntities context)     
    {     
        _context = context;     
    }     

    public int Add(T entity)     
    {     
        _context.AddObject(typeof(T).Name, entity);     
        int saveValue = _context.SaveChanges();     
        return saveValue;     
    }     


    public void Dispose()     
    {     
        if (_context != null)     
            _context.Dispose();     
    }
}
```

The class destructor (`~DataRepository()`) and the `GC.SupressFinalizer()` are not necessary because you don't have any unmanaged resources to release.  Many would argue that it's part of the `IDisposable` pattern, but IMO it's unnecessary.

Also, this:

```
new DataRepository<Customer>().Dispose();
```

is completely redundant and unnecessary.  What you're doing here is creating this object *only* to destroy it.  It has no other function and is just waste of memory/cpu cycles.

Comment: public void Dispose() 
    { GC.SurprizeFinalize(this); }   IS OK??? for  ErpEntities?

Comment: You don't need a `Dispose()` method on `ErpEntities` at all.  You only need `Dispose()` when you have something that needs to be disposed of, like the database connection or a file handle, or something like that.  `GC.SurpriseFinalize()` only needs to be used if your class has a finalizer, and you don't really need a finalizer unless you have unmanaged resources that you _must_ be sure you dispose of properly.

Comment: // ErpEntities class that needs disposing  what do you mean?

Comment: That's a continuation of the comment line above it.  As I said, you have nothing in the `ErpEntities` class that you need to dispose of; so you can get rid of the `IDisposable` interface and implementation.

Comment: You can not use  using (DataRepository<Customer> repository = new DataRepository<Customer>(new TestErpEntities()))
            {
                return repository.Add(new Customer() { Name = Name, SurName = SurName });
            }   WITHOUT IDISPOSE it is necessary

Comment: You need the `IDisposable` on your `DataRepository<T>` class, _not_ your `ErpEntities` class.  doing `using(DataRepository<Customer> repositor = new DataRepository<Customer>)) { ... }` calls `Dispose()` on your `DataRepository`.  There is nothing to dispose of in `ErpEntities`.

Answer (score 1):

From what you posted, `ErpEntities` doesn't need to implement IDisposable. It doesn't 'own' anything.

If it did, `new ErpEntities().SaveCustomer(...)` would be the wrong way to use it.

The  `DataRepository` class doesn't need the destructor (`~DataRepository()`) and the call(s) to `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` can all be removed too.

What you should be left with:

- if a class contains (owns) an IDisposable class it should implement IDisposable as well and forward the calls to Dispose()
- the calling code should use IDisposable classes in a `using(...) { }` block.
- don't mess with destructors unless you have an unmamaged resource (and even then there are better options)

Comment: how can i call  public void Dispose()     
    {     
        if (_context != null)     
            _context.Dispose();     
    }

Comment: @Phsika: you can call it like any other method but a using-block is better.

Comment: look please Coding Gorilla . how can i call  public void Dispose()     
    {     
        if (_context != null)     
            _context.Dispose();     
    }

Comment: @coding has a decent sample and @Steven posted a link to a good example. Just read up on IDisposable, don't just copy code.